# Removing outliers above 3SD above the mean of a time series profile

Tags: r

Removing outliers (by column) above 3 standard deviations of the median in R with multiple columns in a time series. I want to remove the row that has an outlier.

In the example below, the last row would be removed because there is an outlier in column B.

See example data and output

Example data

```
A B   C 
1 0.1 2
2 0.2 3 
3 0.3 4 
4 0.4 5
5 8.0 6
```

Example output

```
A B   C 
1 0.1 2
2 0.2 3 
3 0.3 4 
4 0.4 5
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 3SD above the median?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant median.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably base your cut on the median rather than the mean!

```
> d <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=c(0.1*(1:4),8), C=2:6)
> cut <- apply(d, 2, quantile, 0.997)
> sel <- apply(d, 1, function(x) all(x<cut))
> d[sel,]
  A   B C
1 1 0.1 2
2 2 0.2 3
3 3 0.3 4
4 4 0.4 5
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I meant median. Is this code for the median or the mean?

Comment: The code is for the median, `quantile(x,.997)` returns the value of the 3rd SD for `x` for normally distributed data. A more standard approach is to exclude data outside of 3 interquartile ranges, that is `median + 3*(q(.75)-q(.25))/2` or, in code: `cut <- apply(d,2,median) + (3/2)*(apply(d,2,quantile,0.75) - apply(d,2,quantile,0.25))`, but not `cut <- 2*apply(d,2,median)+3*apply(d,2,sd)`, because `sd` also be strongly affected by outliers.